# Iterating a table in SQL Server using datareader

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am iterating a `incidentNoReserve` tbl in SQL Server. On button click, if it matches a variable the entire row will be deleted from `incidentNoReserve` tbl.

This is the code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (var cmd106 = new SqlCommand("select * from [dbo].[incidentNoReserve]", cnn))
        {
            cnn.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd106.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var commonNo = reader["incidentNoReserveId"];
                //Every new row will create a new dictionary that holds the columns
                if (Convert.ToInt16(commonNo) == newLastIncidentNo )
                {
                    var cmd107 = new SqlCommand("Delete from[dbo].[incidentNoReserve] where incidentNoReserveId = @newLastIncidentNo", cnn);
                    cmd107.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newLastIncidentNo", newLastIncidentNo);
                    cmd107.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                cnn.Close();
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // If an exception occurs, write it to the console
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        cnn.Close();
    }

    this.Close();
}
```

The `newLastIncidentNo` have 18 and while it reaches commonNo it have 10 which is only the first row in `incidentNoReserve` table.

What could be the problem?

Comment: no need to close connection inside `while loop` update your code and check.

Comment: as you said value of newLastIncidentNo  is 18 , is there any matching row with value incidentNoReserveId = 18 in your incidentNoReserve table

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the connection **in** the loop

And you are using the same connection to loop and update

Comment: i fixed it but its not entering this scope :
'if (Convert.ToInt16(commonNo) == newLastIncidentNo )
                        {
                            cnn.Open();
                            var cmd107 = new SqlCommand("Delete from[dbo].[incidentNoReserve]  where incidentNoReserveId = @newLastIncidentNo", cnn);
                            cmd107.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newLastIncidentNo", newLastIncidentNo);
                            cmd107.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            cnn.Close();
                        }'

Comment: Gee maybe it is !=

Comment: its reaching the sql command and stops on cnn.open() and jumps outside the scope

Comment: @R.JN This has to be one the worst problem statement I have tried to answer.  You say it reaches commonNo and now you say it does not.   You have a Catch.  Voting to close.

Comment: Sir, what i meant that if commonNo(in tbl Id)  == newLastIncidentNo(integer on form) row having this Id is deleted from tbl i dont know what's wrong with my explanation

Comment: Really so you say it gets there and you say it does not get there and you don't get the problem.  I am sorry I tried to help

Answer (score -1):

it worked i have just removed the inner open and close connection.Thanks ALL

Answer (score -1):

i fixed it like this :

```
 while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        int commonNo = Convert.ToInt16(reader["incidentNoReserveId"]);
                        //Every new row will create a new dictionary that holds the columns
                        if (Convert.ToInt16(commonNo) == newLastIncidentNo)
                        {
                            reader.Close();
                            //newLastIncidentNo = (Convert.ToInt16(commonNo));
                            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Delete from [dbo].[incidentNoReserve] where incidentNoReserveId = @newLastIncidentNo", cnn))
                            {

                                //MessageBox.Show(newLastIncidentNo.ToString());
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newLastIncidentNo", newLastIncidentNo);
                                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    cnn.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
```